# Avoid kafka disk to became 100% used by Cron job

Tags: linux, hadoop, kafka, big-data

We want to suggest the following based on our issues on kafka disks

We have many HDP clusters ( based on ambari , and all machines are redhat version 7.2 )

Each cluster include 3 kafka machines , while each kafka include disk with ~15 T

Because we have many issues that disk increased to 100% used capacity ( kafka Retention from some reason not works as should be )

Then we think about cron job that will run on kafka machines every min

And when kafka disk size will be for example - ~90%

then cron job will stop all kafka brokers ( kafka service )

And by this we avoid the kafka disk to became 100% , ( as all know when disk is 100% then the purging process will not works )

Please share your opinion

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/articles/apache-kafka-best-practices-to-optimize-your-deployment has a lot of good advice.

Comment: I would recommend to apply retention policy instead of cron,